# How to select id's which contains just special values?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, having

I need help with a sql query. I have a table like this:

```
ID          bookType   Date
----------- ---------- ------
1           85       01.01.2014
1           86       01.01.2014
1           88       01.01.2014
1           3005     01.01.2014
1           3028     01.01.2014
2           74       01.01.2016
2           85       01.01.2016
2           86       01.01.2016        
3           88       01.01.2015
3           3005     01.01.2015
```

I need a query, that returns just all id's with booktype 85, 86 and NOT id's with booktype 88,3005,3028. All the other types are not relevant, they can be included.

Example:

I just want ID 2, because there is no booktype of 88, 3005, 3028. It have the id 74, but this doesn't matter, it can be included.

I tried something like this:

```sql
SELECT bookid AS id, COUNT(bookid) AS number
FROM books
WHERE date BETWEEN '01.01.2014' and '01.01.2016'
  and booktype in (85,86)
GROUP BY bookid
HAVING COUNT(bookid) >1
MINUS
SELECT bookid AS id, count(bookid) AS number
FROM books
WHERE date BETWEEN '01.01.2014' and '01.01.2016'
  and booktype in (88,3005,3028)
GROUP BY bookid;
```

It doesn't work. I get every time results with booktype 88 or other included.
I tried `EXCEPT`, but Oracle SQL Developer doesn't know it.

Comment: Both 85 and 86, or is one of them enough?

Comment: both. And then i need 85,86,88 without 3005 and 3028..

Comment: Does it matter if the 88, 3005, 3028 values are between those dates or not?

Comment: They can be between. I just need id's containing type 85,86 without the other types. If you take a look at the table is the result i need just id 2 and not 1

Comment: Your table have no rows outside those two dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see some inconsistency between your SQL and your columns names.

There is no bookid in the table and you miss booktype...

So assuming your first query is:

```
SELECT ID AS ID, COUNT(ID) AS number FROM books WHERE date
BETWEEN '2014-01-01' and '2016-01-01' and bookType in (85,86)
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(ID) >1;
```

This will have result set:

```
ID        number
 1          2
 2          2
```

Your second query

```
SELECT ID AS ID, COUNT(ID) AS number FROM books WHERE date
BETWEEN '2014-01-01' and '2016-01-01' and bookType in (88, 3005, 3028)
GROUP BY ID;
```

This will have result set:

```
ID        number
 1          3
 3          2
```

The MINUS operator in ORACLE returns only unique rows returned by the first query but not by the second. So the whole query will return first record set as both results of first query are different from the results of the second.

If you drop the count statement in your query you will have:

First query

```
SELECT ID AS ID FROM books WHERE date
BETWEEN '2014-01-01' and '2016-01-01' and bookType in (85,86)
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(ID) >1;
```

result set

```
ID 
 1          
 2
```

Second query:

```
SELECT ID AS ID FROM books WHERE date
BETWEEN '2014-01-01' and '2016-01-01' and bookType in (88, 3005, 3028)
GROUP BY ID;
```

result set

```
ID 
 1          
 3
```

and applying the MINUS operator you will get just 2 as required, as 1 is in the second result set.

This is just to confirm that your logic was right, but did not completely take in account the way the MINUS operates on result sets.

So your query has to be:

```
SELECT ID AS ID FROM books WHERE date
BETWEEN '2014-01-01' and '2016-01-01' and bookType in (85,86)
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(ID) >1
MINUS
SELECT ID AS ID FROM books WHERE date
BETWEEN '2014-01-01' and '2016-01-01' and bookType in (88, 3005, 3028)
GROUP BY ID;
```

Last remarks:

- I left WHERE date BETWEEN '2014-01-01' and '2016-01-01', as I thought it is relative to other requirements also if is not relevant in your example
- I left HAVING COUNT(ID) >1, as I thought it is relative to other requirements also if is not relevant in your example

Regards

Comment: This seems legit. Could you give me a query with minus? i treid it, but i get a "query block has incorrect number of result columns" error

Comment: I tried your query, but it causes the error i posted in comment above

Comment: SORRY, I made a copy and past mistake, not dropping count on the second query, so there was a column mismatch. Try the one I just edited.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT bookid AS id, COUNT(*) AS number
FROM books
WHERE date BETWEEN DATE '2014-01-01' and DATE '2016-01-01'  
GROUP BY bookid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN booktype IN (85,86) THEN booktype END) = 2 AND
       COUNT(CASE WHEN booktype IN (88, 3005, 3028) THEN 1 END) = 0
```

If you just want to count `(85,86)`occurrences then use :

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN booktype IN (85,86) THEN 1 END)
```

instead of:

```
COUNT(*)
```

Comment: Sorry, but i doesn't work. I get nothing back (no result)

Comment: @user3189986 It should work. Are you using the exact same query?

Comment: If you use strings as date values Oracle will implicitly try to convert the string to a date using `TO_DATE()` using the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` parameter as the format mask. This is prone to breaking (without changing the query) as this parameter is a client session value and will be a pain to debug. It would be better to use ANSI date literals `DATE '2016-01-01'` which is independent of the NLS settings or to use the explicit format mask `TO_DATE( '01.01.2016', 'DD-MM-YYYY' )`.

Comment: @ Giorgos Betsos I had a mistake in my example query: Its not SELECT bookid AS id, COUNT(bookid) AS number
FROM books
WHERE date BETWEEN '01.01.2014' and '01.01.2016'
  and **bookid** in (85,86) its SELECT bookid AS id, COUNT(bookid) AS number
FROM books
WHERE date BETWEEN '01.01.2014' and '01.01.2016'
  and **booktype** in (85,86)

Comment: @user3189986 OK, check the edit I made. Is booktype of type int?

Comment: Thank you for your help and time! The solution in the under your post helped

Comment: @user3189986: I don't see why this answer shouldn't work. It's the typical approach to the problem, because it has the advantage that the table is read just once.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner it does not work as there is a bit of confusion on column names. My queries worked because I used ID instead of bookid. I tested this query with the right column names and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  select id,booktype,daata,
    count(*) over (partition by id) count
    from tmp;
```

after tmp; you can put where id=2 or whatever you want:)